# javascript function not working in onclick inside iframe

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm using a website to get some service, the website has a button to submit a webform with confirmation by alert.

The web site not working in most windows PC in  chrome, firefox and IE
after open the message source i found the below code for the submit button but its inside iframe

```
<input class="button" onclick="javascript:openAlertWindowForCehck (); " type="button" value="submit">
```

im trying to enable every think related to java from all browesers including install some addons and add the web site to white list but  its never work. 
based on my knowledge the function (openAlertWindowForCehck ();) 
should found in same html page or his parent bu i never find it what the solutions?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Please show us what you try at least.

Comment: We can't debug a third party site for you. You should contact their technical support instead.

Comment: My question not to solve the problem i have good knowledge about web programming, my question why i cannot find javascript function inside html or is thiere any setting with broswsers to enable the function even if not find